# Spring Security testing with Mockito - Unable to create SecurityContext

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-security

I have written a test method to test a POST request to an API. Every time I run it it returns this error: Unable to create SecurityContext.

I am a beginner with Java and Spring and security (so go gentle on me). I'm taking an online course that asked us to create a recipe API then secure it with Spring Security. I have verified all of the end points with Postman, but am unable to pass a test using Mockito and mockMVC.

Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7.8

## Recipe Controller

Including only the POST request here.

```
package cn.RecipeAPI.Controllers;

import cn.RecipeAPI.Exceptions.NoSuchRecipeException;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Models.Recipe;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Services.RecipeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/recipes")
public class RecipeController {
    @Autowired
    RecipeService recipeService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createNewRecipe(@RequestBody Recipe recipe, Authentication authentication) {
        try {
            Recipe insertedRecipe = recipeService.createNewRecipe(recipe, authentication);
            return ResponseEntity.created(insertedRecipe.getLocationURI()).body(insertedRecipe);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

## Recipe Service

```
package cn.RecipeAPI.Services;

import cn.RecipeAPI.Exceptions.NoSuchRecipeException;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Models.CustomUserDetails;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Models.Recipe;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Models.Review;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Repositories.RecipeRepo;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Repositories.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class RecipeService {
    @Autowired
    RecipeRepo recipeRepo;
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Transactional
    public Recipe createNewRecipe(Recipe recipe, Authentication authentication) throws IllegalStateException {
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        recipe.setUser(userRepo.getReferenceById(userDetails.getId()));
        recipe.validate();
        recipe = recipeRepo.save(recipe);
        recipe.generateLocationURI();
        return recipe;
    }
}
```

## Recipe API Tests

This class may include many unnecessary annotations and things. As I read through many Stack Overflow answers and the Spring Security documentation I tried various fixes. At this point I can't remember what's necessary and what's not.

```
package cn.RecipeAPI;

import cn.RecipeAPI.Controllers.RecipeController;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Exceptions.NoSuchRecipeException;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Models.*;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Security.SecurityConfig;
import cn.RecipeAPI.Services.RecipeService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;



@WebMvcTest(RecipeController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class RecipeApiApplicationTests {
    @Mock
    private Authentication authentication;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private RecipeService recipeService;
    @MockBean
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    // I'm not sure if either of these are needed, but I'm going to leave them in for now
    @InjectMocks
    private RecipeController recipeController;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    // Create some test users
    // user for recipes
    UserMeta userMeta = UserMeta.builder().email("recipe@gmail.com").name("recipeUser1").build();
    Role role = Role.builder().role(Role.Roles.ROLE_USER).build();
    Set<Role> roles = Set.of(role);
    CustomUserDetails userRecipe = CustomUserDetails.builder().userMeta(userMeta).username("userRecipe").password("1234").authorities(roles).build();
    // user for reviews
    UserMeta userMeta1 = UserMeta.builder().email("review@gmail.com").name("reviewUser").build();
    CustomUserDetails userReview = CustomUserDetails.builder().userMeta(userMeta1).username("userReview").password("1234").authorities(roles).build();

    // Create some test recipes
    Review review = Review.builder().description("was just caramel").rating(3).user(userReview).build();
    Review review2 = Review.builder().description("was just egg").rating(4).user(userReview).build();

    Recipe recipe = Recipe.builder().name("test name").difficultyRating(1).minutesToMake(5)
            .ingredients(Set.of(Ingredient.builder().name("spam").amount("1 can").build()))
            .steps(Set.of(Step.builder().stepNumber(1).description("eat spam").build()))
            .locationURI(new URI("http://localhost:8080/recipes/1"))
            .reviews(Set.of(review))
            .id(1L)
            .user(userRecipe)
            .build();
    Recipe recipe2 = Recipe.builder().name("test name2").difficultyRating(2).minutesToMake(6)
            .ingredients(Set.of(Ingredient.builder().name("egg").amount("1 egg").build()))
            .steps(Set.of(Step.builder().stepNumber(1).description("crack egg").build()))
            .locationURI(new URI("http://localhost:8080/recipes/2"))
            .reviews(Set.of(review2))
            .id(2L)
            .user(userRecipe)
            .build();
    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recipe, recipe2));

    public RecipeApiApplicationTests() throws URISyntaxException {
    }
@Test
    @Order(4)
    @WithUserDetails(value="userRecipe", userDetailsServiceBeanName="customUserDetailsService")
    public void testCreateNewRecipeSuccessBehavior() throws Exception {
        when(recipeService.createNewRecipe(any(Recipe.class), any(Authentication.class))).thenReturn(recipe);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes")
                        //set request Content-Type header
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        //set HTTP body equal to JSON based on recipe object
                        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(recipe))
                )
                //confirm HTTP response meta
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                //confirm Location header with new location of object matches the correct URL structure
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", containsString("http://localhost:8080/recipes/1")))

                //confirm some recipe data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("id").value(1))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name").value("test name"))

                //confirm ingredient data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients[0].name").value("spam"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients[0].amount").value("1 can"))

                //confirm step data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("steps", hasSize(1)))
//                .andExpect(jsonPath("steps[0]").isNotEmpty())

                //confirm review data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("reviews", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("reviews[0].username").value("idk"));
    }
}
```

## Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(setupBefore=TEST_METHOD, userDetailsServiceBeanName="customUserDetailsService", value="userRecipe")
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.lambda$createTestSecurityContext$0(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:126) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:73) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293) ~[spring-test-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:174) ~[spring-test-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65) ~[na:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.findUserDetailsService(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:76) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:58) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:43) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.lambda$createTestSecurityContext$0(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:123) ~[spring-security-test-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

## Other

While reading through the [Spring documentation on testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html) I did see this note.
[image]

I tried adding spring-test-4.1.3.RELEASE to my dependencies and that made everything go wrong. It's the only place I've seen that mentioned. I removed it.

Is there anything else I should have included?

Comment: Your test is a mess. You are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 and I have no clue on what you want to use of those. You are using `@WebMvcTest` but also an `@ContextConfiguration` which doesn't really make sense. You autowire mockmvc but then discard that and do it yourself in a setup method. Trying to add `spring-test-4.1.3` will indeed make things go wrong even more, as spring boot 2.7 uses Spring 5.3, mixing jars from different versions of a framework is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: If you scroll down the error stack you will see the actual error message: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' available

Comment: Thanks Pavel! I didn't notice that.

Comment: After setting some breakpoints in the Controller, I realized that the test never hits the Controller so now I'm investigating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much to M, Pavel, and Nikita for helping me on this. Turns out that my SecurityConfig class was never being picked up by my tests. This was fixed by adding `@Import(SecurityConfig.class)` to the test class.

From Nikita: Starting from 2.7.X the regular @Configuration beans are not picked up by testMvcTest. See [17.15.3. Structure @Configuration classes for inclusion in slice tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.testing.slice-tests)

Here's the final test class, which passes now.

```
@WebMvcTest(RecipeController.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class RecipeApiApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    // Create some test users
    // user for recipes
    UserMeta userMeta = UserMeta.builder().email("recipe@gmail.com").name("recipeUser1").build();
    Role role = Role.builder().role(Role.Roles.ROLE_USER).build();
    Set<Role> roles = Set.of(role);
    CustomUserDetails userRecipe = CustomUserDetails.builder().userMeta(userMeta).username("userRecipe").password("1234").authorities(roles).build();
    // user for reviews
    UserMeta userMeta1 = UserMeta.builder().email("review@gmail.com").name("reviewUser").build();
    CustomUserDetails userReview = CustomUserDetails.builder().userMeta(userMeta1).username("userReview").password("1234").authorities(roles).build();

    // Create some test recipes
    Review review = Review.builder().description("was just caramel").rating(3).user(userReview).build();
    Review review2 = Review.builder().description("was just egg").rating(4).user(userReview).build();

    Recipe recipe = Recipe.builder().name("test name").difficultyRating(1).minutesToMake(5)
            .ingredients(Set.of(Ingredient.builder().name("spam").amount("1 can").build()))
            .steps(Set.of(Step.builder().stepNumber(1).description("eat spam").build()))
            .locationURI(new URI("http://localhost:8080/recipes/1"))
            .reviews(Set.of(review))
            .id(1L)
            .user(userRecipe)
            .build();
    Recipe recipe2 = Recipe.builder().name("test name2").difficultyRating(2).minutesToMake(6)
            .ingredients(Set.of(Ingredient.builder().name("egg").amount("1 egg").build()))
            .steps(Set.of(Step.builder().stepNumber(1).description("crack egg").build()))
            .locationURI(new URI("http://localhost:8080/recipes/2"))
            .reviews(Set.of(review2))
            .id(2L)
            .user(userRecipe)
            .build();
    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recipe, recipe2));

@Test
    @Order(4)
    @WithMockUser("userRecipe")
    public void testCreateNewRecipeSuccessBehavior() throws Exception {
        when(recipeService.createNewRecipe(any(Recipe.class), any(Authentication.class))).thenReturn(recipe);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes")//.with(user(userRecipe))
                        //set request Content-Type header
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        //set HTTP body equal to JSON based on recipe object
                        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(recipe))
                )
                //confirm HTTP response meta
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                //confirm Location header with new location of object matches the correct URL structure
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", containsString("http://localhost:8080/recipes/1")))

                //confirm some recipe data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("id").value(1))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name").value("test name"))

                //confirm ingredient data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients[0].name").value("spam"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("ingredients[0].amount").value("1 can"))

                //confirm step data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("steps", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("steps[0]").isNotEmpty())

                //confirm review data
                .andExpect(jsonPath("reviews", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("reviews[0].author").value("userReview"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by selecting a framework either JUnit4 or JUnit5 but not both. I suggest the latter as that is the most recent. With that you should remove some of the annotations on your test.

```java
@WebMvcTest(RecipeController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class RecipeApiApplicationTests { }
```

When using `@WebMvcTest` this will auto configure Spring Boot with a minimal context to execute your controller. It will also setup `MockMvc` for you, so you should autowire it. You don't need the controller, webapplication etc. on your class. As `@WebMvcTest` already includes `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` you can remove that as well. Your class  definition should be something like the following.

```java
@WebMvcTest(RecipeController.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class RecipeApiApplicationTests { }
```

As you should be autowiring `MockMvc` and not create it yourself ditch the `setup` method as well as some of the fields you don't need.

```java
@WebMvcTest(RecipeController.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class RecipeApiApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    @MockBean(name="customUserDetailsService")
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    // Your data fields for testing go here
```

Notice the added name to the `CustomerUserDetailsService` mock. Probably not really needed as it should take the name of the field or the existing bean it will replace.

Now re-run your test. If that doesn't work make sure that you are using the same name in your `@WithUserDetails` annotation as the name of your actual `UserDetailsService` in your application.

Comment: Hey M, thanks so much for your detailed response. I have applied your suggested changes and am still getting the same error.

My CustomUserDetailsService is, in fact, called CustomUserDetailsService and the import statement looks correct to me.
```import cn.RecipeAPI.Security.CustomUserDetailsService;```

Comment: I was referencing the name of the bean in your configuration **not** the name of the class.